# How it is possible to create and insert a stored procedure with EF Core 3

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-core-3.0

I'm looking for a way to load my procedures stored in my MySQL database, using Entity Framework Core 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your SP using this:

```
var res = context.[DbSet]
                 .FromSql("EXECUTE [SP] @_param1,@_param2", val1, val2)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I think this is a way to run a stored procedure, Now, I'm looking for how to load the code of the stored procedure via EF Core